# installing Ruby rails, Could not locate gemfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to Learn ruby atm. am having alot of problems installing ruby on rails on my computer.  I'm Using the one click installer and this how to install tutorial.http://www.hashemzahran.com/riding-the-rails-installing-ruby-on-rails/

My first problem i ran into was that it couldn't find the lib file.  so i created and a new lib folder and believe i corrected that problem

now though when i try to run bundle install i get the error "Could not locate gemfile" i found I've been checking around through Google but have not been able to find an answer to the question.  I'm running Windows 7 if that matters.

thanks for any help you can give me.  I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Are you trying to learn Ruby, Ruby on Rails, or both?

Comment: what version of ruby are you trying to install?

Comment: version 1.9.2-p180.  haha and ya i guess im trying to learn both.

Answer (score 0):

install through this guide..

[ruby on rails](http://rubyonrails.org/download)

try to install ruby-1.9.2-p180

Comment: tried installing it with the link you sent me.  i installed the first two links fine.  When i ran gem install rails in "start command prompt with ruby" i run into two different errors                                    --Installing ri documentaion for rails=3.0.9...                            file 'lib' not found                                                   --Installing Rdoc documentaion for rails-3.0.9...                        file 'lib' not found